# Can a class library add an IDbInterceptor automatically?

Tags: configuration, initialization, entity-framework-6, class-library

I'm in the early stages of building a new N-tier application. I'm using Entity Framework in the data layer and am going to use an `IDbConnectionInterceptor` to set the tenant ID prior to executing queries in order to take advantage of SQL Server 2016 Row Level Security. The only way I'm aware of to add this interceptor is to call

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterception.Add(new MyContextInterceptor(tenantIDProvider));
```

So I've put this into a static `Initialize()` method that the consuming application must call when it starts up. Is there a way to automatically add this interceptor by default so that the consuming application doesn't have to know or remember to call `Initialize()` on my class library when it starts up? If it can't automatically happen, can I at least do it in a config file somehow?

Comment: Why not ensure it is called once in your dbcontext constructor?

Comment: That is a good idea as a validation step. I think it would still be more user (developer) friendly if it can be done automatically or via config file so you don't have to run it and find an exception to realize you missed the step.

Comment: No, I meant call the above interception creation method once in your DbContext constructor.

Comment: That might work. I don't see a way to check if the interceptor has already been added so I'd have to keep create my own static flag, I think. That flag should probably also not be "owned" by my DBContext because it looks like an added interceptor applies to all contexts. Last, I think I'd have to make sure my flag is thread-safe since the constructor could be called in parallel, right?